# Как принять запрос от сервера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Есть Router

Например когда переходишь на страницу /about получить что-то от сервера.

Как это можно сделать ? (использую proxy)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={about} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);


const Home = () => (  
   <div>Home</div>
);

const about = () => (
<div>        
    

</div>
);


export default BasicExample;
```

Answer (score 0):

Подключить axios для запросов на сервер https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios
В нужном компоненте в функции componentDidMount() - сделать запрос на сервер

```
axios.get('/user')
 .then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать абсолютно стандартный XMLHttpRequest.
Вот простой пример его использования.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', '/about', false);

xhr.send();

// Обрабатываем ответ
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  // обработчик ошибки
  console.log( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); 
} else {
 // обработать результат
 console.log( xhr.responseText ); 
}
```